# How to copy polygon using mouse click?

Tags: java, copy, drawing

How to make a copy of a polygon using mouse click (e.g. when the mouse click, a menu pop up showing menu for copy).

I have problem to differentiate a mouse click, to draw or to copy. I created a method 
where when the user pressed the mouse, the method will check if the mouse pressed inside existing polygon or outside. If it outside polygon it will draw a new polygon. If it outside it will move the polygon. How am I able to copy the polygon?

```
.....
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {                    
  startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
  endDrag = startDrag;
  repaint();                
  for(Polygon p:triangles){                     
     if(p.contains(startDrag)){ // if inside polygon triangle, mark the triangle
    selectedTriangle = p;
    break;
     }
  }
}

....

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
   Polygon[] triArray = triangles.toArray(new   Polygon[triangles.size()]);
   if (e.getClickCount() ==2) {
      for (Polygon p:triArray){
     if (p.contains(startDrag)) {//Polygon has a 'contains(Point)' 
      triangles.remove (p);
          break;
     }
     }
 }
```

Comment: But how do you know what triangle you want to copy. I see you are using an array. So you will have more triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the button pressed from the mouse event.  Such as

```
    int button = e.getButton();
    if(button==MouseEvent.BUTTON1){

    }else if(button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){

    }
```

See the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) for MouseEvent for more info.

Comment: Better way to do this in platform independent manner is to use MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger() instead.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem using JPopupMenu ...thanks a lot.